# I get the error: Value of type 'Bundle' has no member 'pathForResources'

Tags: ios, swift

Here is the code causing the error:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var BackgroundAudio = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.mainBundle.pathForResources( "Music", ofType: "mp3")!),error: nil)
}
```

Edit:
I am creating a rock paper scissor game with audio here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let backgroundAudio : AVAudioPlayer = {let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Music", withExtension: "mp3")!
        return try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)

    }()
    let controller = ViewController()
    controller.backgroundAudio.play()
        @IBOutlet weak var cpuImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var playerImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var cpuScore: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var playerScore: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    @IBAction func rockButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        playerMove = 1
        playerImage.image = UIImage(named: "playerRock.png")
        computerChoice(cpuImage: cpuImage)
        determineWinner(player: playerScore, cpu: cpuScore)
    }

    @IBAction func paperButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        playerMove = 2
        playerImage.image = UIImage(named: "playerPaper.png")
        computerChoice(cpuImage: cpuImage)
        determineWinner(player: playerScore, cpu: cpuScore)
    }

    @IBAction func scissorButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        playerMove = 3
        playerImage.image = UIImage(named: "playerScissor.png")
        computerChoice(cpuImage: cpuImage)
        determineWinner(player: playerScore, cpu: cpuScore)
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up Swift 2 and 3 code and even in Swift 2 there is no `pathForResources` (plural) API.

If you are looking for an URL use the URL related API:

```
Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Music", withExtension: "mp3")
```

and the `AVAudioPlayer` initializer `throws`

```
do {
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Music", withExtension: "mp3")!
    let backgroundAudio = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

In this case you can even write

```
   let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Music", withExtension: "mp3")!
   let backgroundAudio = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
```

because the initializer will succeed always (if it does not it's a design error).

**Edit:**

This is a way to create the audio player with a closure

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let backgroundAudio : AVAudioPlayer = {
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Music", withExtension: "mp3")!
        return try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
    }()

}
```

and play the sound

```
let controller = ViewController()
controller.backgroundAudio.play()
```

---

PS: Do not use `NS...` classes like `NSURL` if there is a native Swift counterpart (`URL`)

Comment: I copied your code like this: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Music", withExtension: "mp3")
    do {
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Music", withExtension: "mp3")!
    let backgroundAudio = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
    } catch {
    print(error)
    } I get the error Declaration expected

Comment: You cannot put this code on the top level of the class. Put it in a method like `viewDidLoad` or declare the player lazily.

Comment: I did what you said and ran it but no sound came out. Is there something I am missing? I copied your Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Music", withExtension: "mp3") do {
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Music", withExtension: "mp3")!
    let backgroundAudio = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
} catch {
    print(error)
} Code. Thank you.

Comment: You need to call `play()` on the player to play the sound. I updated the answer to show you a way to create the player with a closure. Using a closure you can put the code on the top level of the class.

Comment: I am so sorry but where do  put the let controller = ViewController()
controller.backgroundAudio.play() part. I put it in view did load part but, no sound. I also put it in the class viewcontroller but, an error came up saying declaration expected.

Comment: I ran the code in a Playground. If the code is in `viewDidLoad()` it's supposed to play the sound when the view is loaded. As already mentioned in any case you have to call `play()` on the player.

Comment: How would you add play(). Where exactly? Sorry I am new to swift and am struggling to do this?

Comment: `backgroundAudio.play()` Please search on google for *AVAudioPlayer example swift*

Comment: Sorry here is my current code with your suggestions: class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let backgroundAudio : AVAudioPlayer = {
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Music", withExtension: "mp3")!
        return try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
       
    }()
    let controller = ViewController()
    controller.backgroundAudio.play()

Comment: What are you going to accomplish? Nobody can know that just from the code snippet. If you want to run the code in a Playground you have to add the audio file to the `Resources` folder and these two lines: `import PlaygroundSupport` `PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true` to allow asynchronous code execution

Comment: According to your edited question delete the lines `let controller = ViewController()` and `controller.backgroundAudio.play()` and add `backgroundAudio.play()` in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Thank you so much it works now. With this will it keep playing forever?

Comment: No, it plays the sound once. You have to set the `numberOfLoops` property to a negative value to loop the sound indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

The function you are calling in your first line is not named like that anymore. Use this instead:

```
var BackgroundAudio = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Music", ofType: "mp3")!),error: nil)
```

Comment: I did that but I got this error: Argument labels '(contentsOfURL:, error:)' do not match any available Overloads

Comment: @Gammaslash132 This answer does not say to use `contentsOfURL:`. It states to use `contentsOf:`.

Comment: @Terje - Do not use `NSURL`. Use `URL`.

Comment: Thank you I fixed it later but, am currently trying someone else's suggestion. Thank you though.

Comment: Yeah I saw that someone else had answered and gotten you further so that's cool :). BTW: if you have problems like this in the future, a good way of getting past it is either to check the documentation for the function or constructor you are trying to use or to type it out on a new line, like "AVAudioPlayer(" and see what the autocomplete helps you with!